# "And" used in a list with no comma

Tags: phrase-usage, lists

I have no trouble reading the following, even though they say not to use "and" twice in a sentence without a comma:

> The bulk of the expense came from all the lost opportunities and all the rabbits and other fluffy tailed creatures needed during the implementation phase.

Why is this allowed?  Does it have to do with grouping?

Comment: It depends on what kind of shoe you're wearing.

Comment: The kind of shoes worn on the east coast I presume.

Comment: Actually, the kind of shoes worn northwest of London.

Comment: I meant to ask left or right.

Comment: https://www.businessinsider.com/history-of-the-oxford-comma-2016-1

Comment: Nobody actually says that you shouldn't use more than one *and* in a list. Many writers do so for literary effect and it's perfectly acceptable. It's just that, unless done for a particular purpose, it can look strange. But it's definitely *allowed*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The bulk of the expense came from all the lost opportunities and all the rabbits and other fluffy tailed creatures needed during the implementation phase.

"Rabbits and other fluffy tailed creatures" is one item in a two item list ("lost opportunities" and "rabbits and other fluffy tailed creatures").   The above sentence might also be written as follows:

> The bulk of the expense came from all the lost opportunities and all the fluffy tailed creatures, including rabbits, needed during the implementation phase.

Since it is only a two item list, no comma is necessary.